# BigQuery split array into individual rows

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery I have done a `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` query and have results where each row contains multiple lines (an array).

How can query this table to convert each row's array into its own row so that my resulting table is individual rows of each line, instead of an array?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can apply the [unnest](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays) operation. As an example:

```
WITH data AS(
  SELECT ['string1', 'string2'] AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT ['string3', 'string4', 'string5']
)

SELECT
r
FROM data,
UNNEST(r) r
```

Comment: This query first showed just single 'string1' for me, but the web UI was buggy and reloading the page helped.